# Why does output differ based on what comes before my command

Tags: powershell, formatting

The commands

```
Write-Host "`r`nSource Hosts" -BackgroundColor Green
$myEvents | Group-Object Host -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
Write-Host "`r`n`r`nAccounts" -BackgroundColor Green
$myEvents | Group-Object User -NoElement | sort-object Count -Descending
```

create nice, tabulated output when handed a nice array of PSObjects

The entire script is quite short:

```
(Get-Date)
$Events= Get-WinEvent -ComputerName MYDC -FilterHashtable  @{Logname='Security';id=4740;StartTime=(Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)}
$TargetEvents=@()
function OutputEvents($myEvents) {

    Write-Host "`r`nSource Hosts" -BackgroundColor Green
    $myEvents | Group-Object Host -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
    Write-Host "`r`n`r`nAccounts" -BackgroundColor Green
    $myEvents | Group-Object User -NoElement | sort-object Count -Descending
}
foreach ($Event in $Events)
{

    $obj=[PSCustomObject]@{
        Host=$Event.Properties[1].value.ToString()
        User=$Event.Properties[0].value.ToString()
    }
    $TargetEvents+=$obj
}
(Get-Date)
OutputEvents $TargetEvents
```

The problem is that when it runs in this context, I end up with

```
Source Hosts

Values : {HOSTNAME}
Count  : 5
Group  : {}
Name   : HOSTNAME
...etc

Accounts

Values : {Username}
Count  : 5
Group  : {}
Name   : Username
...etc
```

But after the code has run I can copy and paste the output lines and get:

```
Source Hosts

Count Name                     
----- ----                     
5 APSPRW7082  
...etc

Accounts
5 SVOL.EM       
...etc
```

Two completely differing formats

I don't understand why, and quite frankly, I'd like it to stop.

Comment: your function is outputting an array of GroupInfoNoElement items. so the display system showing an array of objects. when you get those objects directly, they are NOT wrapped in an array ... so the display system treats them differently. ///// if you want the 2nd format, you will need to deal with that in the function OR deal with it after the function finishes.

Comment: if I remove the (Get-Date) command the script formats the code correctly...

Comment: Is you problem that the output is displayed wrong or is it that it is copy/pasted wrong? If it's the ladder, where are you pasting?

Comment: No the problem is incorrect display... when (Get-Date) is there, the format is messed up.  When it's NOT there, the format is "correct"

Comment: ah! you did not fully describe the problem earlier. the reason  the `Get-Date` is messing up the format is because of how the display system tries to group "similar items" to display them. if you add `| Out-Host` to the `Get-Date` line just before your `OutputEvents` call ... the display is as you expected. ///// the problem is the display system trying to group things ... and doing so in ways that make no sense to people. [*grin*]

Comment: Can you turn that into an answer and expound a bit on it... It was the fix.  I'm still not entirely sure WHY, but it was the fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the way to ensure that the format works correctly is to take the output lines:

```
$myEvents | Group-Object Host -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending
```

and convert them to:

```
$myEvents | Group-Object Host -NoElement | Sort-Object Count -Descending | ft
```

Thereby ensuring that the output is table formatted and not let PS make some arbirtrary "helpful" decision for me.

Answer (score 1):

The script runs through format-table implicitly.  With another set of properties output by get-date, powershell tries to handle the output in a different way.